# Incorrect font size css for special characters

Tags: css, special-characters, font-size

Help reduce the size of special characters to other characters. It happens like this text with special characters, they do not decrease with CSS font-size: 12px; and beyond.

> ➓WhoOtyLand ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ⎛⎝snap:delilahd26⎠⎞TEST.xas

**What is the way to fix it?**

Comment: Can you show us some code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

What font are you using? This is how I would build a test area for this:

I'm not totally sure what your question is about. Please try and clarify. : )

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Lgk3zt5p/

This seems work...

content

```
<p class='five'>
  5 ➓WhoOtyLand ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ⎛⎝snap:delilahd26⎠⎞TEST.xas
</p>


<p class='ten'>
  10 ➓WhoOtyLand ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ⎛⎝snap:delilahd26⎠⎞TEST.xas
</p>


<p class='twenty'>
  20 ➓WhoOtyLand ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ⎛⎝snap:delilahd26⎠⎞TEST.xas
</p>


<p class='fourty'>
  30 ➓WhoOtyLand ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ⎛⎝snap:delilahd26⎠⎞TEST.xas
</p>
```

style

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.five {
  font-size: 5px;
}

.ten {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.twenty {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.fourty {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: it does not work, I use Arial, decrease occurs but special characters higher than its counterparts.

Comment: Weird. It doesn't look like that on my end.